# unable to import module from python egg file

Tags: python, import

I created a python egg file. I have the appended the egg path to sys.path and when I import the python module in the egg file then it works if i'm directly doing it from a script. But when the same thing doesn't work in my application, where script A calls script B and script B try to set the sys.path() and import the module. I'm not sure what is the difference and why it is not working in scenario 2. Any help is appreciated.

Egg contains the following files:

testing/sample.py

testing/**init**.py

Step 1(test1.py):It works

```
egg_path = /var/local/sample.egg

sys.path.append(egg_path)

from sample import test
```

Step 2 (test2.py): It doesn't work

```
import testmode

testmode.py:

egg_path = /var/local/sample.egg

sys.path.append(egg_path)

from sample import test
```

not sure what is wrong. Both has root as owners. test1.py permission is set to 600 permissions and test2.py and testmode.py has 755 permissions.

Comment: Add more details. What **exactly** are you doing and **how**? Be specific.

Comment: This code isn't even valid Python syntax...

Comment: don't worry about syntax. The syntax is fine. I need help only with importing a module from a python egg file.